# Why does Euphoria never show Rue undressed?

Tags: analysis, euphoria

Please don't get me wrong - I'm not fishing for nude photos of Zendaya (the actress playing Rue Bennett), but the TV series *[Euphoria](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8772296/)* is full of nudity, to the point where you could make a drinking game from taking a shot whenever you see somebody's penis.

But seriously, the show is full of nudity and most of the time it is not fanservice - quite the contrary, as even beautiful people are usually displayed in quite naturalistic (read - unattractive) ways: drunk, confused, troubled. But not Rue: even when she is forced to strip at gunpoint in S02E01, the camera skips that moment, showing instead the rest of the group standing naked.

Is this a purposeful artistic choice made by the director or rather a demand made by the actress?

Comment: Apparently the actress, like many others, has a "no nudity clause" but I can't find "official" confirmation. Frankly though I think this is a "trivia" question.

Comment: Plus: good for her.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think it is trivia - the way Rue is presented on screen is hugely different from the rest of the teenagers (as her focus are drugs rather than causal sex), so it makes me wonder is a director's choice rather than "no nudity" clause.

Comment: @Yasskier - it's definitely part of her character too. While Zendaya may have a clause, the show could always use a stand-in or such for her character.